# Sorting incoming bluetooth devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Every time I scan for devices the list shows the same ~10 devices repeated in a seemingly random order. None of the attempts ive made to make sure they appear once have worked. Any ideas?

```
 private final no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18.scanner.ScanCallback mScanCallback = new no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18.scanner.ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);

        Log.i("onScanResult", "device detected");

            device = result.getDevice();
            String deviceName = device.getName();
            String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();

            Log.i(DEVICE, "Scanned device: " + device.toString());
            Log.i(DEVICE, "Scanned device name: " + deviceName);
            Log.i(DEVICE, "Scanned device address: " + deviceAddress);


        deviceShowFormat deviceObj;

//            if(foundDevices.size() == 0){
//                foundDevices.add(new deviceShowFormat(device, deviceName, deviceAddress));
//                BTadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//            }
        boolean isThere = false;
        for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
        {
            try {
                deviceObj = foundDevices.get(i);

                Log.i("Sorting1", "" + i);
                if (deviceObj.get_device_address() == deviceAddress){
                    isThere = true;
                }
            } catch(Exception e){}

        }

        if(!isThere){
            foundDevices.add(new deviceShowFormat(device, deviceName, deviceAddress));
            BTadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            isThere = false;
        }


    }
};
```

Comment: If you are using a ListView control connected to an adapter, you need to add an update method to your adapter and call it with the newly updated list. Set the datasource behind your list, and then call notifydatasetchanged

Example in Kotlin code 

    /*
    * Triggers a refresh on the impact list
    * @data: New data to apply
     */
    fun updateData(data: Array<AlertImpact>) {
        this.dataSource = data
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? I have notifyDataSetChanged() in there, are you saying to create a method in the adapter with notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: I had to add it to the associated adapter

Comment: Does your adapter inherit from BaseAdapter()?

Comment: @TaylorMaxwell my adapter inherits from ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Now, I know I’m not an expert at java or the android java sdk but this is rather simple no?
You can create an unordered set / dictionary and add each of the names. If the name is in the list, don’t add it again. Using a set is better for time complexity. It will be O(n) to check through the list.

Comment: I agree that it shouldnt be that hard but when I implement it like "if looked up not in list then add" for some reason the UI List doesnt update.